# Python Regex: how to escape characters inside double quotes only

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I'm totally not skilled in regex usage so I would need your help to achieve one probably very simple task. I'm working with Pytohn2.7 and I need to escape double quotes and backslashes in my target string, but only if they are enclosed inside double quotes. Let me show this with an example.
Let's use this initial string:

```
'NotEscaped"S\tr"ing"'
```

Python representation of this is actually:

```
'NotEscaped"S\\tr"ing"'
```

I would like it to become (again Python representation):

```
'NotEscaped"S\\\\tr\\"ing"'
```

So, my task is actually to put a backslash character (\\) before every backslash or every double quotes I find in my string if they are enclosed in double quotes.
Can someone help me to write the right regex for this? or, if regex is not the right tool, can you point me out the right approach to do that?

Comment: There's no way to know if a double quote is a closing double quote or a nested double quote (except if you are sure there's only one quoted part in your string).

Comment: Just have the entire string be a regex and then use the regex of `'Escaped\\Backslashes'` which in Python would be, `r'Escaped\\\\Backslashes'`.

Comment: You can do it with string slicing pretty easily. something like : `s[:s.find('"') + 1] + s[s.find('"') + 1:s.rfind('"')].replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('"', '\\"') + s[s.rfind('"'):]` (this assumes you wanted everything between the first and last quotes escaped).

Comment: This is only solvable if you know the contexts for the initial and closing `"`s.